# Translation "I always start working after exercising"

Tags: grammar, translation

I am trying to translate:

> I always start working after exercising
> Or equivalently
> I always exercise before start working
> Or (sligthly different)
> I cannot work if I don't exercise

My attempt:

> 저는 우동하고 나서 일하기를 비롯해요

Explaining my attempt

1. I am using the pattern ~고 나너 to express temporal sequence between clauses.
2. On the verb 일하다 I am attaching ~기 to the stem so I get the noun 일하기 (working). Also I've further used the object particle ~를
3. In the dictionary I've found 비롯하다 as "to begin/to start".

For the third variation I gave:

> 만일 우동 안 하고 일하수 없어요

Where I am using the sentential adverb 만일. Also 고 expresses to me "then" and finally the pattern 수 없다" to express inability to perform. Maybe I could've used the conjunctional adverb 그리고 to say "then"

Is it correct? What are my mistakes

Comment: 만일 운동 안 하면 일할 수 없어요. '만일' indicates an assumption. Which should be followed by a corresponding ending. Therefore, it should end with '~면'. Also if you want to use  '수', it should be 일할 수 (있다/없다). Or just use 일하지 못해요.

Comment: @Bihrang 일아지 못해요 instead of what? the whole sentence?

Comment: 만일 운동 안 하면 [일할 수 없어요. / 일하지 못해요.]

Comment: In English "*I always start working after exercising*" isn't a natural expression. Taken literally, it could mean that while I frequently work, on those rare occasions that I happen to exercise, afterward I get a sudden urge to do some work. I think your intended meaning is "I always exercise before working.".  In general, the "always" part of a sentence is the result of the other part, not the cause. Compare with "I always hiccup when I eat peppers" (because they irritate my diaphragm) and "I always eat peppers when I hiccup" (because they cure the problem).

Answer (score 0):

> I always start working after exercising.
> 저는 언제나 (or 항상) 운동하고 나서 일하기 시작해요.
> 저는 늘 운동을 한 다음에 일하기 시작해요.

비롯하다 is a very formal word which means "to start" only in certain contexts, like describing an important event. You will almost never hear it in this sense in a real life situation. **시작하다** is the word that is at least a thousand times more common, especially when talking about routine things as in your example.

-고 나서 and -(으)ㄴ 다음에/뒤에/후에 are all common phrases for "after (doing something)".

> I cannot work if I don't exercise.
> (만일) 운동(을) 안 하면 일할 수(가) 없어요.
> (만일) 운동하지 않으면 일을 못해요.

An "if" clause translates to -(으)면.  만일 adds the sense that it is an unlikely case, so it is not really necessary in a routine description like this.

운동(을) 안 하면, 운동(을) 하지 않으면, 운동하지 않으면 are all variations of the same phrase having to do with contraction. 일할 수(가) 없어요, 일을 하지 못해요, 일하지 못해요 are all similar too since -(으)ㄹ 수(가) 없다 and -지 못하다 have about the same meaning in this context.